# conectar mariadb con python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mariadb

tengo el siguiente problema cree este codigo con el proposito de  eejcutar mariadb:

```
from tkinter import *
import mariadb 

root=Tk()


try:
    conexion = mariadb.connect(
    user="root",
    password="",
    host="127.0.0.1",
    port=3386,
    database="prueba"

)

Label(root,text="se conecto a la base de datos" + conexion.database).pack()

except mariadb.Error as error:
    print(f"error de base de datos: {error}")

print("fallo")
mainloop()
```

pero al momento de ejecutar no responde ningún atributo ni tampoco ejecuta el print para saber si ya termino ademas estoy usando xammp y phpmyadmin

Comment: Corrige la indentación del código, que creo que ha quedado mal probablemente a causa del corta-pega. Para que te respete la indentación ponle una línea de ``` delante y otra detrás.

Answer (score 0):

Añado el código con la indención correcta:

```
from tkinter import *
import mariadb 

root=Tk()


try:
    conexion = mariadb.connect(
    user="root",
    password="",
    host="127.0.0.1",
    port=3386,
    database="prueba"
    )

    Label(root,text="se conecto a la base de datos" + conexion.database).pack()

except mariadb.Error as error:
    print(f"error de base de datos: {error}")
    print("fallo")

mainloop()
```

Si te sigue dando error, actualiza tu pregunta con dicho error.

Toma en cuenta también que `tkinter import *` se considera una mala practica, lo recomendable es `import tkinter as tk` y luego utilizar la librería de la siguiente manera `tk.Text`, `tk.Label` y así sucesivamente.